# Why are completion handlers of [UIView animate] called in a wrong order?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

In my project there's a ViewController which contains a few subviews(e.g. buttons).
It shows/hides those buttons, always with animation.

It has an interface like this:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController

- (void)setMyButtonsVisible:(BOOL)visible;

@end
```

And an implementation looks like this:

```
- (void)setMyButtonsVisible:(BOOL)visible
{
    if( visible )
    {
        // "show"
        _btn1.hidden = NO;
        _btn2.hidden = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            _btn1.alpha = 1.0;
            _btn2.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // "hide"
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            _btn1.alpha = 0.0;
            _btn2.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            _btn1.hidden = YES;
            _btn2.hidden = YES;
        }];
    }
}
```

When `[_myVC setMyButtonsVisible:NO]` is called, and then *after some time ( > 0.2s)* `[_myVC setMyButtonsVisible:YES]` is called, everything is OK.
However, it `setMyButtonsVisible:YES` is called *immediately after ( < 0.2s)* `setMyButtonsVisible:NO`, the animations overlap and `setMyButtonsVisible:NO` callback is called the last.

I've tried to change "hide" duration to 0.1, it doesn't help - after "hide(0.1)"+"show(0.2)" calls, "hide" callback is called after the "show" callback and my buttons are not visible.

I've added a quick-fix by caching the `visible` param and checking in "hide" completion handler if the state should be `!visible`.

My questions are:

1. Why the first animation completion handler is called the last if animations overlap?
2. What are better approahes to discard a previous "overlapping" animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the *finished* flag on completion:

```
if (finished) {
 _btn1.hidden = YES;
 _btn2.hidden = YES; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this flag is indeed useful, strange I've missed it :)